# Chosen and If Statements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-chosen

I integrated Chosen into my three drop downs. I have created a function so if any selection is made in the first drop down, the second drop down appears. Then if any selection in the second drop down is made, the third appears.

I want to alter my code so that only a specific selection triggers the next drop down to appear. For example, if "clean" is the value selected in the first drop down, then the second will appear. In summary, I want to change the trigger from any value to a specific value. How would I go about doing this? Thanks so much!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Experiment</title>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.7/chosen.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.7/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      $(".chosen-select").chosen({
        disable_search_threshold: 4
      });

      function hide() {
        $("#p1").parent().hide();
        $("#p2").parent().hide();
      }
      // call hide AFTER .chosen() has been invoked on the visible elements
      hide();
    });
  </script>
  <script>
    function onSelect1() {
      $("#p1").parent().show();
    }

    function onSelect2() {
      $("#p2").parent().show();
    }
  </script>
  <style type="text/css">
    .chosen-select {
      width: 200px
    }
  </style>
</head>
<!-- Do not call hide() on body load -->
<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td onchange="onSelect1()">
        <select class="chosen-select">
          <option value="" disabled selected>Title</option>
          <option value="clean">Clean</option>
          <option value="salvage">Salvage</option>
          <option value="rebuilt">Rebuilt</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td onchange="onSelect2()">
        <select class="chosen-select" id="p1">
          <option value="" disabled selected>Title Status</option>
          <option value="in hand">In Hand</option>
          <option value="lien">Lien</option>
          <option value="missing">Missing</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select class="chosen-select" id="p2">
          <option value="" disabled selected>Title Stat</option>
          <option value="in hand">In Hand</option>
          <option value="lien">Lien</option>
          <option value="missing">Missing</option>
          <option value="ralph jr.">Missing</option>
          <option value="ralph">Missing</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use chosen's change function

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Experiment</title>

  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.7/chosen.css">

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.7/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      $(".chosen-select").chosen({
        disable_search_threshold: 4
      });
      
       $("#p0").chosen().change(function(){
        if ($(this).val() === 'clean'){
          $("#p1").parent().show();
        }
    });
      
      
      function hide() {
        $("#p1").parent().hide();
        $("#p2").parent().hide();
      }
      // call hide AFTER .chosen() has been invoked on the visible elements
      hide();
        
    });
  </script>

<script>

  function onSelect2(){
    $("#p2").parent().show();
  }
</script>


  <style type="text/css">
  .chosen-select {width:200px}
  </style>
</head>
<!-- Do not call hide() on body load -->
<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <select  class="chosen-select" id="p0">
          <option value="" disabled selected>Title</option>
          <option value="clean">Clean</option>
          <option value="salvage">Salvage</option>
          <option value="rebuilt">Rebuilt</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td onchange="onSelect2()">
        <select class="chosen-select" id="p1" >
          <option value="" disabled selected>Title Status</option>
          <option value="in hand">In Hand</option>
          <option value="lien">Lien</option>
          <option value="missing">Missing</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select class="chosen-select" id="p2">
          <option value="" disabled selected>Title Stat</option>
          <option value="in hand">In Hand</option>
          <option value="lien">Lien</option>
          <option value="missing">Missing</option>
          <option value="ralph jr.">Missing</option>
          <option value="ralph">Missing</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>




</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I'd suggest using a switch statement vs. if-then statements: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp though either would work.

Answer (score 1):

Just use

```
function onSelect1(){
  if ($("#p1").value() == 'whatever')
       $("#p1").parent().show();
}
```

in your onSelect function

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can do it, by checking select value on `change` event for first selection.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".chosen-select").chosen({
    disable_search_threshold: 4
  });

  function hide() {
    $("#p1").parent().hide();
    $("#p2").parent().hide();
  }
  // call hide AFTER .chosen() has been invoked on the visible elements
  hide();
});

function onSelect1(event) {
  if (event.target.value === "clean")
    $("#p1").parent().show();

}

function onSelect2() {
  $("#p2").parent().show();
}

$("#select1").on('change', onSelect1);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Experiment</title>

  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.7/chosen.css">

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.7/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>

  <style type="text/css">
    .chosen-select {
      width: 200px
    }
  </style>
</head>
<!-- Do not call hide() on body load -->

<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td id="select1">
        <select class="chosen-select">
          <option value="" disabled selected>Title</option>
          <option value="clean">Clean</option>
          <option value="salvage">Salvage</option>
          <option value="rebuilt">Rebuilt</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td onchange="onSelect2()">
        <select class="chosen-select" id="p1">
          <option value="" disabled selected>Title Status</option>
          <option value="in hand">In Hand</option>
          <option value="lien">Lien</option>
          <option value="missing">Missing</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select class="chosen-select" id="p2">
          <option value="" disabled selected>Title Stat</option>
          <option value="in hand">In Hand</option>
          <option value="lien">Lien</option>
          <option value="missing">Missing</option>
          <option value="ralph jr.">Missing</option>
          <option value="ralph">Missing</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>




</body>

</html>
```